# Получение и вывод на экран данных из атрибут?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая задача. Пользователь видит на экране изображение и вопрос, что изображено на картинке?
У пользователя должна быть возможность ввести только правильный ответ.
Например, на картинке изображен лес. У пользователя, в данном случае, есть возможность ввести слово ЛЕС.После правильного ответа на экран выводится другое изображение и т.д.
В моем варианте условие работает частично, т.е. пользователь имеет возможность ввода этих трех символов в любой последовательности.
Перепробовал все в рамках своих знаний на данный момент. Не смог решить проблему. Требуется помощь. Спасибо.

```
 <div class="item  one" value="лес"></div>

let Word = document.querySelector(".pick");  //вывод на экран
 let content = document.querySelector(".item");
let attr =content. getAttribute("value");// атрибут 
let alfabet = document.querySelectorAll(".num");// клавиатура

alfabet.forEach((elem) => {
  elem.onclick = function () {
       if (attr.includes(elem.innerHTML)) {
         word.innerHTML += elem.innerHTML;
       }
     }
  });
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: "ввести слово ЛЕС" - куда ввести?

Comment: набрать на клавиатуре.

Comment: Экранная клавиатура что ли?

Comment: Да. Совершенно верно.

Comment: На какой клавиатуре? Собственно говоря, я свой минус уже поставил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');
let output = document.querySelector('.output');
const word = 'лес';

input.addEventListener('input',function() {
   let index =  output.innerText.length;
   let letter = word.split('').splice(index,1);   
   if (this.value == letter) output.innerText += letter;
   this.value = '';
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Pavel Nazarian. спасибо за код.  Мне кажется . доработав ваш код я сумею решить свою проблему. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @Yuber я уж не стал экранную клавиатуру верстать. У меня слушатель на инпуте, вам надо будет на ваши кнопки повесить. И слово из атрибута получать ,как у вас сейчас и сделано.

Comment: Огромное спасибо.  Код до конца не дописал. но уже вижу . что проблема решена.